# window opener focus, or active

Tags: javascript

i want to open a window in a new tab, but when i want that opener page to be active, not the new one. How can i do this... Many thanks

my code is something like this :

```
  <script language="javascript">
  window.open("http://www.google.ro");
  window.opener.location.focus();
  </script>
```

Comment: Just for clarification: The code above is in the parent window, or the child window?

Comment: is in the parent window. On my page i have banners, when i click on it i have a details page about it, and the clients want when they click on the banner, then open my details page and their website, but i want to remain in my website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give focus to the new window (but you don't want that, and it will probably have focus by default):

```
var newWindow = window.open("http://www.google.ro", '_blank');
newWindow.focus();
```

I don't think it's possible to steal the focus from the new opened tabs. I didn't find any official statement telling this, but all the articles I found on this subject talk about configuring your browser to open tabs by default without focus.

The only "solution" I could come up with is this one:

```
window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
window.alert('Hello there! This is a message that annoys you, the user.');
```

*Note that it is possible to shift focus when opening popups.*

[Learn more about the `window` object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window)

Comment: I think the OP wants a pop-under.

Comment: Man not the newWindow, i want the opener window to focus on it

Comment: In my case is not on the same domain...Ahh

Comment: @cosy I've done some experimenting. I don't think it's possible even with the same domain. Its a security issue. The browser consider the action malicious and doesn't allow shifting focus from new windows. It is possible for popups though. As a separate note, I managed to restore focus by throwing an alert, but I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: merci mult, vad ca esti tot din bucuresti. Vad ca merge cu alert, dar nu e ceea ce vroiam, dar daca gasesti o solutie pliss help!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me...

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://www.google.ro', '_blank', 'height=300,width=300,menubar=0,status=0,toolbar=0', false);

window.focus();
```

Comment: This works for me too, and is what I thought the OP was asking for - open a new tab but have the focus remain on the current tab. *However* I see a flash where the new tab opens, very briefly takes the focus, and then the initial tab regains the focus. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

To give back focus to the opener window, try using `window.focus(window.name);` instead of `window.opener.location.focus();`