# How can I bring browser to front/ in focus of all other window or browsers after 3 seconds using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way out to bring browser to front/ in focus of all other window or browsers using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: This is not possible in JS alone as control of the active window is done at OS level which JS cannot control.

Comment: I don't you can do this with JavaScript or jQuery, because for this scenario you want access of process on operation system and javascript can't access this.

Comment: Take a look on [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454189/2115584) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for good reason; imagine the possibilities for spammy pages to force their page to the top.

You can call attention to the window by changing the title periodically (e.g., every second or so), or through [web notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) in supported environments.